# How can I access props passed in Vue router, inside a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a route defined below:

```
{
  path: 'fit-details',
  name: 'fit-details',
  component: Fitment,
  props: true

},
```

I'm passing props through my route with data from the state:

```
this.$router.push({ path: 'fit-details', query: { 
    year: this.query.year, 
    make: this.query.make,
    model: this.query.model
  }
})
```

I see the route getting properly defined when passed: `www.placeholder.com?year=2008&make=Acura&model=MDX`

And finally inside my receiving component I have the props instantiate:

```
export default {
  props: ['year', 'make', 'model'],
},
```

However I can't access this data in the component for some reason. Any help would be much appreciated, Im honestly not the best when it comes to Vue router stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to define that props inside the visited component, you could use `this.$route.query.year` and `this.$route.query.make` or you could do something like :

```
const {'year', 'make', 'model'}=this.$route.query
```

or :

```
{
  path: 'fit-details',
  name: 'fit-details',
  component: Fitment,
 props:(route) => ({ year: route.query.year,make:route.query.make,model:route.query.model })

},
```

in `Fitment` component :

```
export default {
  props: ['year', 'make', 'model'],
},
```

Comment: I need to access the props in the visited component though, thats my main question

Comment: please check my edited answer to the second solution

Comment: That worked thank, I wonder if there is a cleaner approach to condensing to a singular object, but this worked so I appreciate it